# Why when i enter with the mouse into the richTextBox area its loading all the text over again?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace TextParsing
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string readText;
        string htmlFile;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            htmlFile = @"C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\HtmlFilesDirectory\Sat24_Cloudtypes_Europe.html";
            readText = File.ReadAllText(htmlFile);
            richTextBox1.Text = readText;
            HighlightPhrase(richTextBox1, "http", Color.Red);

        }

        static void HighlightPhrase(RichTextBox box, string phrase, Color color)
        {
            int pos = box.SelectionStart;
            string s = box.Text;
            for (int ix = 0; ; )
            {
                int jx = s.IndexOf(phrase, ix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                if (jx < 0) break;
                box.SelectionStart = jx;
                box.SelectionLength = phrase.Length;
                box.SelectionColor = color;
                ix = jx + 1;
            }
            box.SelectionStart = pos;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;
        }

        private void richTextBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HighlightPhrase(richTextBox1, "http", Color.Green);
        }
    }
}
```

When im running the program its painting all the http words in the richTextBox1 in Red.
When i enter with the mouse over the richTextBox1 area it will paint all the http words in Green.

But each time im entering the richTextBox1 area its loading like loading over again the text into the richTextBox and then change the colors.
I guess but not sure its the FOR loop in the HighlightPhrase method.

Is there anyway to make it to change the colors without like loading all the text over again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not loading `richtextbox` again and again on mouse enter. It just scroll on the start position when you enter mouse in it. I have checked this by removing position lines. Try as given below.

```
static void HighlightPhrase(RichTextBox box, string phrase, Color color)
    {
        string s = box.Text;
        for (int ix = 0; ; )
        {
            int jx = s.IndexOf(phrase, ix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (jx < 0) break;
            box.SelectionStart = jx;
            box.SelectionLength = phrase.Length;
            box.SelectionColor = color;
            ix = jx + 1;
        }
    }
```